# Google Maps trigger Google Analytics Events wen map controls are used

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-analytics, universal-analytics

How to fire Google Universal Analytics events every time Google Maps (V3) controls are used: zoom in, zoom out, terrain, satellite, street view...

This is standard Universal Analytics event:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Event category', 'Event action', 'Event label');
```

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add standard Google Maps event listeners for the following on the map:

- zoom_changed
- maptypeid_changed

e.g.

```
function doYourAnalytics(event) {
  // or whatever you need to call here
  ga('send', 'event', 'Event category', event, 'Event label');
}

map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    doYourAnalytics('zoom_changed');
});
map.addListener('maptypeid_changed', function() {
    doYourAnalytics('maptypeid_changed');
});
```

You don't give any indication what you want for 'Event category', 'Event action', 'Event label', but you can pass any event data you need to your function.  e.g. for the zoom you would maybe want to check the map's current zoom level, work out if they'd zoomed in or out, and then specify that as the event label.